# Cypress cy.type({enter} fails when used multiple times within for loop

Tags: cypress, enter

The cypress cy.type({enter} fails when I use this in a for loop to enter multiple data in text field. If I have to enter only one value then in that case that works.

Please suggest me some solution for this. Here is my code :-

value = cat, bat, mice, fox

```
enterMultipleValue(value) {
        var val = value;
        var val_str = val.split(",");
        for (var i = 0; i < val_str.length; i++) {
            cy.get('input[mat-option="text"]')
                .type(val_str[i]+"{enter}", { force: true });
                // .wait(3000)
                // .type('{enter}');
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works ok, but what do you want to see?

```js
const value = "cat, bat, mice, fox"
const vals = value.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < val_str.length; i++) {
  cy.get('input[mat-option="text"]')
    .type(val_str[i]+"{enter}")
    .wait(3000)
    .type('{enter}');
}
```

This shows "cat bat mice fox" in the input box.

If you want to see them one at a time, add a `.clear()` command

```js
const value = "cat, bat, mice, fox"
const vals = value.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < val_str.length; i++) {
  cy.get('input[mat-option="text"]')
    .type(val_str[i]+"{enter}")
    .wait(3000)
    .clear();
}
```

This shows each one for 3 seconds, then the next, etc.

But is this a select box? `mat-option` is used on an Angular Material Select. Are you trying to do a multiple-select?

Comment: Actually, it is not mat-option. It is just for example. It is a text box to enter some value and search by press enter. And it is weird, it works when you don't use for loop. Like, when you have to enter only one value. I am using for loop only to enter multiple values.

Comment: So, what exactly do you want to see? It looks like it does work.